# How to write SQL to achieve the required output

Tags: sql, rdbms

I have an existing table with the following columns: data_date,portfolio,weight,comments and I will need to generate an additional field called 'factor' by doing some calculation using the existing fields.

(Data shown below is just a sample, there are millions of records)

| data_date | portfolio | weight | comments | factor |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2020-01-02 | A | 0.2 | Exclude | ? |
| 2020-01-03 | B | 0.3 | - | ? |

The 'factor' field is calculated using the formula:

```
(select sum(weight) from TABLE_A 
  where comments != 'Exclude' group by data_date,portfolio) 
divide by
(select sum(weight) from TABLE_A group by data_date,portfolio)
```

How can I write a select statement such that it will include all the existing 4 columns with the nicely calculated factor field?

Any help or suggestion is appreciated! Thank you!

Tried with multiple with clause but still can't get the results right.

Comment: Why do you talk about sql ? I only see a dataframe and pandas methods

Comment: Add tag for RDBMS used.

Comment: That generic rdbms tag does not identify the RDBMS used - SQLServer, MySQL, Oracle, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use sum window function as the following:

```
Select data_date, portfolio, weight, comments,
   Sum(Case When comments != 'Exclude' Then weight Else 0 End) Over (Partition By data_date,portfolio) /
   Sum(weight) Over (Partition By data_date,portfolio) As factor
From TABLE_A
Order By data_date, portfolio
```

See a [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/bE222VIO).

Comment: I've managed to get it working! Thanks for your prompt help!

Comment: Happy for you, Good Luck :)

Answer (score 0):

After trying to understand your question, I believe more data is needed. Given below is a code that you can copy paste and run directly on your SSMS window and you shall see that your dividend query/requirement gives one sum while the second query/requirement which is the divisor has two outputs.

```
declare @tableA table(
data_date date,
portfolio varchar(5),
[weight] numeric(18,8),
comments varchar(15),
factor varchar(5)
)

insert @tableA
select '2020-01-02','A',0.2,'Exclude','?'
union
select '2020-01-03','B',0.3,'-','?'

select sum([weight]) 
from @tableA 
where comments not in ('Exclude')
group by data_date, portfolio
```

Output: 0.30000000

```
select sum([weight])
from @tableA
group by data_date, portfolio
```

Output: 0.20000000
0.30000000

This is clearly because you are grouping by date and there are two different dates and Portfolios.
Thus, your requirement is not clear and would need more data on what you need exactly.

Comment: Hello, have edited the question, the two rows of data are just sample, there are a lot more records which I have omitted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried this in MySQL
You can modified base on your usage
So basically you will have the factor by day.
And you can try fill in all data in your table.

- Sum all weight not exlcuded ( or null )
- Sum all weight
- Divide them together

```
SELECT data_date,portfolio,sum_not_exclude_weight,sum_all_weight_final,sum_not_exclude_weight/sum_all_weight_final as factor FROM
  (SELECT sum_not_excldue.data_date,
          sum_not_excldue.portfolio,
          sum_not_exclude_weight,
          sum(sum_all.sum_all_weight_by_day) AS sum_all_weight_final
   FROM
     (SELECT data_date,
             portfolio,
             sum(weight) AS sum_not_exclude_weight
      FROM TABLE_A
      WHERE TABLE_A.comments != 'Exclude'
        OR TABLE_A.comments IS NULL
      GROUP BY data_date,
               portfolio) AS sum_not_excldue
   LEFT OUTER JOIN
     (SELECT data_date,
             sum(weight) AS sum_all_weight_by_day
      FROM TABLE_A
      GROUP BY data_date,
               portfolio) AS sum_all ON sum_all.data_date = sum_not_excldue.data_date
   GROUP BY sum_not_excldue.data_date,
            sum_not_excldue.portfolio) AS result
```